# convertion between physical and logical adresses

Tags: paging

Consider the following paging table within a memory management system with one-level paging. The pages size is 1024 bytes, physical memory is 2MBytes and logical address space size is 16 MBytes:

page frame

0   4

1    2

2     16

3     17

a) To what physical address does the logical address 1524 corresponds to?
b) To what logical address does the physicall address 4100 corresponds to?
c) How many bits are necessary for each entry of the page table?
d) what the maximum number of entries within a page table?

I would very much appreciate justified answers. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Physical Memory=2MB=2^21

```
           ==>21 bits to identify physical address.
```

Logical Memory=2^16=256KB

```
          ==>16 bits to identify logical address.
```

Page size=1024 bytes

```
     =2^10
```

Number of pages=2^16/2^10

```
           =2^6 ==>6 bits to identify page number

           =64 Pages.
```

**a) To what physical address does the logical address 1524 corresponds to?**

1524==>(0000010111110100)

6 bits to identify Page number

Page number=000001=1

So frame number for page 1(from given table) is 2.

The offset within page will remain same for both logical and physical address.

So rightmost 10 bits will be same.

So Physical address is ==> 0000 0000 010 01 1111 0100

```
                   ==>2548
```

**b) To what logical address does the physical address 4100 corresponds to?**

Physical address is of 21 bits.

So 4100 can be written as:

0 0000 0001 0000 0000 0100

Leftmost 11 bits will identify frame number.

Frame number = 0 0000 0001 00

```
         =4.
```

Page Number for frame 4 ==> 0

Logical address ==> 0000 00 00 0000 0100 (Rightmost 10 bits will be same.)

Logical Address = 4.

**c) How many bits are necessary for each entry of the page table?**

Each page table entry will contain frame number.

Frame number requires 11 bits.

**d) what the maximum number of entries within a page table?**

Number of entries in page table = Number of pages

```
                            =64.
```

I hope it will you......

Comment: Rupsingh I was now looking again to your answer and there is one thing I dont know how you did come up with. In a) when you say that offset within page will remain the same...why is that? Thank you

Comment: And why do you say logical memory is 2^16??